# who is hidding NPE in junit parameterized tests?

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, junit

I have junit parameterized test.

During debug I see an exception is thrown from junit framework:

```
public abstract class ReflectiveCallable {
    public Object run() throws Throwable {
        try {
            return runReflectiveCall();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        }
    }
```

However when I look at the console in my Intellij I don't see this exception.

how can I make it visible in the console?

Comment: Show a test that causes this exception so that we might understand the context.

Comment: Does the test appear red in the test runner? Or is the Exception otherwise expected or caught and handled some place else?